# write a function which calls from phtml file in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new in magento,
i have create a phtml template file in magento 1.9.
i that phtml i have create a html form. i want to call a function after submitting that form. i am little confused how i should write a function shall i create a controller or a block or in same phtml i have write a function.
please guide me with correct 
`

```
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content-row">
                <h2>PLEASE ENTER</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>name</label><br><br> 
                        <input class="form-control" maxlength="2">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It is linked with [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). To make it short, you need to write a new action on the controller.

For example, if your form is supposed to send an email you can write in the controller that is responsible for the display of your form a new method called `sendAction()`. In this method, you will make a check of your form and send an email if it must be.

Blocks hold logics of the block itself (retrieve data that will be displayed for example)

Phtml files are only for the display and even though you can see in Magento files phtml with logic its a bad habit and has historical reasons.

To finish, if the logic of your form is held by the Magento controller you need to [override the controller](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) and neither touch the `Core`.

Comment: Thank you so much. But actually my form is a popup and it will directly shown on homepage so there are no any other folders like controller block. that is why i am confused how i can create a controller directly and how i can link

Comment: In that case, create your own module with the controller you need and use geturl function for the action. It can be managed with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways you an do this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Here is an simple example how you can run your JS on form submit.

```
<form name="yourform" onsubmit="your_script()" >
    <input type="text" name="text"/>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

function your_script() {
//your script here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it a good way to write a function just below html form in phtml. As it will become much code in phtml file

Comment: You can actually add it include it in your .xml file  <reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>path/thescript.js</script></action>  **OR**
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>path/thescript.js</name></action>
  </reference>